# Mongoengine query listfield

Tags: python, django, mongoengine

I have the following model:

```
class Deal(Document):
    stores = ListField(ReferenceField('Store', dbref=False), required=True)

class Store(Document):
    fb_page_id = StringField(verbose_name=_('Facebook PageId'), default="")
```

I have try query Deal by store.fb_page_id

```
def get_current_deal_by_fb_page_id(self, request):
    pageid=1556714851256344
    store=Store.objects(fb_page_id=pageid)
    return Deal.objects(stores__fb_page_id=pageid).all()

def get_current_deal_by_fb_page_id(self, request):
    pageid=1556714851256344
    return Deal.objects(__raw__={'stores.fb_page_id': pageid})
```

but I can't get the data. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer:

```
class Deal(Document):
    stores = ListField(ReferenceField('Store', dbref=False), required=True)

    @classmethod
    def deals_by_fb_page(cls, fb_page_id):
        deals = []
        for deal in cls.objects():
            for store in deal.stores:
                if store.fb_page_id == fb_page_id:
                    deals.append(deal)
        return deals
```

Comment: This is will be very inefficient for large dataset